# Sub-Exponential and its Orlicz norm

Tags: probability-theory, inequality, random-variables

Let $Z$ be a sub-Exponential r.v. with mean 0 and variance 1. Can we have a bound on its Orlicz norm, $\| Z \|_{\psi_1}$, both upper and lower?